# Updating tlmgr itself gives error about wrong repository

Tags: tlmgr, macos, update

I've recently upgraded macOS to 13.1. When upgrading TeXLive, the error indicated I need to fix my repository. How?

```
$ tlmgr update --self

/Library/TeX/texbin/tlmgr: TLPDB::from_file could not initialize from: https://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb
/Library/TeX/texbin/tlmgr: Maybe the repository setting should be changed.
/Library/TeX/texbin/tlmgr: More info: https://tug.org/texlive/acquire.html

$ tlmgr --version
tlmgr revision 62273 (2022-02-28 09:52:17 +0100)
tlmgr using installation: /usr/local/texlive/2022
TeX Live (https://tug.org/texlive) version 2022

$ tlmgr repository list
List of repositories (with tags if set):
    http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet (main)
```

In 'TeX Live Utilities.app', under menu item Configuration > Manage repositories, I could NOT find any repository that is obviously more suitable than the current one. Any idea?

Update 2023-1-16T00:24-8:

```
$ sudo tlmgr update --self                                                                                       Password:
tlmgr: package repository https://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/systems/texlive/tlnet (verified)
tlmgr: saving backups to /usr/local/texlive/2022/tlpkg/backups
tlmgr: no self-updates for tlmgr available
```

Just to be sure, this means the update command worked but nothing is available?

Comment: I've added an update with a follow-up question. If you move this to an answer, I can accept it as an answer.

Comment: The last piece of output tells you that there’s no new version of `tlmgr` itself available; for updates to packages, don’t use the `—self` oprion, but `—all`